# can socat exec a program just once when accepting a connection?

Tags: socat

I am trying to invoke a command (mysql CLI) when I connect to a certain port.
This works just fine, except that every time I connect, a new instance of the command is invoked.
Tried to use the end-close option but mysql CLI is killed when I close the connection, and a new one is fired when I reconnect. Command line used is below. Any way to have socat launching the mysql command once, and just reuse that process when new connections arrive? Thanks in advance!

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:$port,reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1,linger=3600 EXEC:"mysql -ANnvvf -u $user -h $host $passstr $portstr $socketstr",end-close
```